# AVPlayer error during mp3 playback

Tags: ios, objective-c, mp3, avfoundation, avplayer

I would like to know why my AVPlayer crashes when I want it to play "some" songs.

[Song #1](http://www.iwheelbuy.com/Player/Test/1.mp3)

[Song #2](http://www.iwheelbuy.com/Player/Test/2.mp3)

That is the way I play these songs:

```
AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iwheelbuy.com/Player/Test/1.mp3"]];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
[player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
[player setRate:1.0f];
```

I have some KVO observers, one of them observes `AVPlayer status` and when I try to play one of these songs it gives me an error:

```
Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800
UserInfo=0x1cdc3be0 {NSLocalizedDescription=..., NSUnderlyingError=0x1cdc14c0
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -303.)"
```

Is there a way to play these songs? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I have succeeded to make these songs play well

```
__block AVPlayer *currentPlayerBlock = _currentPlayer;
__block NSURL *urlBlock = url;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:urlBlock options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [currentPlayerBlock replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
        [currentPlayerBlock setRate:1.0f];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__block AVPlayer *currentPlayerBlock = _currentPlayer;
__block NSURL *urlBlock = url;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:urlBlock options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [currentPlayerBlock replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
        [currentPlayerBlock setRate:1.0f];
    });
});
```

This way it works